# Mishnayot in the Bavli

Tags: mishna, talmud-bavli

In the Miqraot Gedolot, an index exists called Toldot uVeit Aharon. It lists "every" passage in the early rabbinic literature that references every individual *passuk*, and is extremely useful. Another, more fuller, version of the same is the three-volume Torah haKetuvah vehaMesorah. Does anybody know if a similar index exists for the Mishna? I would love to be able to know where any individual mishna is referenced throughout the Bavli and the Yerushalmi.

Comment: Mesoret hashas?

Comment: Mesoret haShas is good if the Shas is your object of study, but not if your object of study is the Mishna. For that, you could *use* Mesoret haShas in order to compile such an index, though it would take a long time, and it would require you to go through the entire Bavli. I would rather target a particular mishna, then see everywhere in the Bavli (and Yerushalmi) that the sages refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one, with a title atop the column that reads "ציונים", in the outside margin of the standard-print *mishnayos* (the one with the *Yachin Uvoaz*).